# Console won't run my code from js file in ATOM? **Beginner

Tags: javascript, console

I'm pressing "cntrl I" to run the code (print to console) from atom but it won't show anything in the console. Here are some screenshots for reference

[image: Network - Error]

[image: Console]

[image: HTML File]

[image: JS File]

Comment: erm, so you couldn't post 10 lines of code in the question?, and my guess is that `/js/myfirstapp.js' is not the right path ... try 'js/myfirstapp.js' or even `myfirstapp.js' for the src attribute

Comment: Move your script to <head>. It should not be in <body>

Comment: @poodle - it can be anywhere you NEED it to be

Comment: `JS/MyFirstApp.js` ... not the same as `/js/myfirstapp.js` ... seriously, use `src="JS/MyFirstApp.js"` - though, is MyFirstApp.js in the JS folder at all? only YOU know where your files are, relative to each other

Comment: That is not working and YES I have myFirstApp.js in the JS file. Thanks for your help though @JaromandaX

Comment: so  `src="JS/MyFirstApp.js"` doesn't work either? how about `src="/JS/MyFirstApp.js"` or `src="MyFirstApp.js"`

Answer (score 0):

`myfirstapp.js` is not being loaded in the browser. You must change the path to your js file from the `index.html` file. Try `<script src="./MyFirstApp.js"></script>` and `<script src="JS/MyFirstApp"></script>`. I can't really tell you because the path depends on how you structured your website. Once you get the file to load, you should see the output from the console.

Comment: It is not a website, I am taking a class and this is the first code we are learning. I've tried to change the path and it's not working, thanks for your help though!